# Will Sunchoke grow from "fingers"?

Tags: vegetables, planting, potatoes

I purchased a Sunchoke from my local organic grocer, and was wondering if a sunchoke, like a potato will grow from its "fingers", and the main ball.

**Edit:**
What I'm meaning specifically is cut the sunchoke fingers off, and plant them individually from a big tuber I purchased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have sunchokes. The bigger the "finger", the more stored energy the tuber has, and the bigger the plant will be. I generally plant fingers/tubers that are at least 1 inch in the thickest portion.

These are fun plants. I even got them to overwinter in the ground in Michigan zone 5b.

Comment: They overwinter fine in zone 3 (and "straight from the frozen ground" is the best way to harvest them.)

Comment: I saw someone planted them in Montana, and they say you can grow them in USDA zone 9.

Answer (score 6):

It will grow from wherever it has the means to sprout, as with potatoes.

It is also almost impossible to eradicate once you establish a bed, so pick your location carefully, thinking about the long term.

Comment: So cut a big one into pieces and plant the pieces?

Comment: Each piece needs at least one "eye" (sprout forming location) same as with potatoes. And give this a gander before you start.... http://commonsensehome.com/before-you-plant-sunchokes/ (the only way I like them is raw, after a good freeze; I like them pretty well that way, though they can be a pain to peel.)

Comment: So it's hardier than a potato?

Comment: I read it last night.